# 'Can/could' difference and usage

Tags: grammar

Should I use **can** or **could** in the following context? Are they both correct? Please explain.

Here's the context:

- John, you have been told not to roam in bare feet outside the house. It is winter and you **can/could** catch a cold if you do so.

Answer (score 1):

They're both 100% correct, but I would choose "could" because it sounds more natural to me.

Comment: You seem to be right. I would add to your opinion that *could* seems to be more polite in the context.